# How to read a too long repo diff

Tags: android, linux, diff, android-source, repo

I'm trying to read the output of the `repo diff` command but it is too long to be shown on the terminal, so I can't read the whole thing. Is there any solution like exporting the output in a file so I can read all the lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe output to less:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD | less
```

Answer (score 0):

- Output to file:

  ```
  repo diff > /tmp/yourdiff.txt
  ```
- You can output it both to the terminal and a file, this way:

  ```
  repo diff | tee /tmp/yourdiff.txt
  ```

  You could open that with any editor you like.

Comment: If you want it to both display and go to a file, you probably meant to put `tee` in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) to save the output to a file (named `repo.diff` in my example):

```
repo diff > repo.diff
```